# Would like to display the index of one specific row in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe I need to iterate through, I have a method to find the value I'm looking for. But I would only need the related index.

let's say I have dataframe like below:

```
Index values
 Q1  45
 Q2  46
 Q3  11
```

Let's say my code finds 46 as the value I'm looking for, but I would like the related index only to put into a string. Q2

I know it should be simple but I was browsing different forums and pandas library but did not find a simple way to do this. This is how my code looks like so far:

```
for ind in GDP_df.index:
    prev_GDP = (GDP_df.iloc[pos1-1:, 0:1]).values[0].item()
    current_GDP = (GDP_df.iloc[pos1:, 0:1]).values[0].item()
    pos1 = pos1+1

    if prev_GDP > current_GDP:
        rec_start = (GDP_df.iloc[pos1:, 0:1])
```

This is where I'm stuck. What syntax should be put here to put only the index into the string?
`rec_start` should hold the index, Q2 in this case.

Please advise.

Comment: I would suggest you use  .index to get the index you are interested in ... so GDP_df.iloc[pos1:,0:1].index. Also, why a for loop? it's usually best to avoid for loops, and I cant tell exactly what u want to achieve though; Pandas and numpy have vectorized methods to make things much much faster.

Comment: Use `for ind, val in GDP_df["values"].iteritems():` if you want to see index and value together. But better is to use Pandas operations (compare `GDP_df["values"]` with `GDP_df["values"].shift()` to find the rows where value is less than the previous line.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the .shift(), but I'm not interested to see a comparison of every line, at the en my code should give back only one year and quarter where GDP recession started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there could be more than one index mapped to your value, you should return a list instead:

```py
GDP_df.iloc[pos1:, 0:1].index.tolist()
```